# Using location_once_scrolled_into_view and want to center

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, python-imaging-library, lxml

I am using location_once_scrolled_into_view to scroll to specific elements on a web page. After I find these elements, I am taking screenshots of them. The problem I am running in to is that the page ends up scrolling up to high and puts the elements underneath the Navigation bar. Once it takes the screenshot it is just a picture of the nav bar. Is there a way to continue using the location_once_scrolled_into_view but have it not scroll all the way to the top of the page. But instead to the center of the page?

Here is the code for my screenshot function:

```
def take_screenshot(element, driver, filename):
    location = element.location_once_scrolled_into_view

    size = element.size
    png = driver.get_screenshot_as_png() # saves screenshot of entire page
    im = Image.open(BytesIO(png)) # uses PIL library to open image in memory



    left = location['x']
    top = location['y']
    right = location['x'] + size['width']
    bottom = location['y'] + size['height']

    im = im.crop((left, top, right, bottom)) # defines crop points
    w , h = im.size
    if w > 0 and h > 0:
        im.save(filename)# saves new cropped image
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use JavaScript `scrollIntoView` with [options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView):

```
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block: "center", inline: "center"})', element)
```